# RichTextBox Text Positioning

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox, text-alignment, text-formatting

I'm building a simple application, but I need to know how to use a RichTextBox and position the text on it, like: center, right and left. But how I can do this?

Comment: WinForms or WPF rich text box?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `SelectionAlignment` property. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.selectionalignment.aspx) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Try the property of selectionChanged and set the Horizantal alignment to either center, right, or left.

```
private void richTxtBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
      richTxtBox.SelectionAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
    }
```